# UTF-8 character in console output

Tags: c, utf-8, printf

I am trying to `printf` a `String` into Windows console using `C` language. Is there any way I could print `↑` or `↓` characters into output?

Comment: Those are not in ASCII.

Comment: Historically, those characters did appear in the control code section of the ASCII table in the DOS shell...  But I'm not familiar with the encoding used in modern Windows Cmd shell.  Perhaps it supports UTF-8?

Comment: So what happens if you do `putc('↑');` or `printf("%s\n", "↑");`?

Comment: So is there any alternative way of showing UP & DOWN graphically? I am reluctant to print plain words.

Comment: What about using `^` and `v`?

Comment: Or MUD-style....  `U` and `D` =P  Am I living in the past?

Comment: @alk former gives error, latter prints strange character in console.

Comment: Should it be `printf("%c\n", "↑");` ?

Comment: @WedaPashi Your guess is wrong.

Comment: Symbols 0 to 31 in the ASCII table are non-printable ones. DOS and other systems abused this and put printable characters on those numbers as well, which is a non-standard extension. Similarly, DOS compiler used various "extended ASCII" tables to print various characters not covered by the the standard 7 bits. In _modern_ programming, you'll use Unicode UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using WinAPI, take a look at [WriteConsoleW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) function. It allows you to print every unicode character to console. You can get corresponding WCHAR representation of your character either with `L"character"` or with [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx). I suggested the second as it is more portable and works for runtime generated strings.

Example (source must be saved in UTF-8):

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    const char* multibyte = "↑↓";
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WCHAR buffer[1024];
    DWORD count;
    DWORD written;
    count = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, multibyte, strlen(multibyte), buffer, 1024);
    WriteConsoleW(handle, buffer, count, &written, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to find out:

1. Researcher Method: Find documentation about the console you are using. Find documentation aboutthe character set it uses and find a way to print the characters which are present in this character set.

   2. Trial and Error: Print all 255 characters to the console in a loop like below.

---

```
for(i=1; i < 256; i++)
{
    printf ("%d: %c\n", i, i);
}
```

This should give you all the information you need ready at your console screen.

Answer (score -1):

Apology for the wrong answer.
After little bit of Searching I found this online

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131226030802AAnvC7n

```
for( i=0;i<256;i++)printf("%d %c\n ", i, ((char) i) ); 

 printf("%c %c %c %c\n", 24,25,26,27); \\This gives those characters.
```

But can you let me know which compiler are you using for this because it is not printing arrows in all compilers.

Comment: I don't know what that page is talking about, but it's not ASCII.  ASCII code 72 is `H`. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yeah tested this. It is working on Turbo C but it isn't working on gcc compiler.

Looking for solution which works everywhere. if found will update the answer